# Hide and show button in oracle MAF

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-maf

How to hide and show the `commandButton` in oracle mobile Application Framework using `AMX`?

Is this possible to do it in `AMX` itself without using `javascript/jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JS.

**Example with using the inlineStyle:**

```
 <amx:commandButton id="c1" text="#{row.name}" inlineStyle="#{row.salary >4000 ? 'display: none;' : 'display: inline;'}">
```

You can also use the rendered attribute as [described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile200/mobile/tag-ref/toc.htm#amx:commandButton).